How do I add a download link for s3 in the markdown?
I managed to file answers with PHP and RUBY but I need to edit download link in a markdown.
I found this
How to download a file from s3 using provided url?
but it requires a new file.
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/mmteres-docs-website?region=us-east-1&bucketType=general&prefix=krivist-1.0.0-RC.tsv

How should the download link look like?

Your question is written in markdown. You linked a page there. That's how you do a link in markdown?!

Writing a link in markdown is pretty straight forward [text](url) there are a lot of in-depth tutorial online.
I think part of what your asking is what link to use? The link you have wont work, that is the link to the object in the console. If your bucket is public you can use the object URL or S3 URI (which should be on the page you linked). If your bucket is private then you can put a cloudfront distribution in front and give the cloudfront permission to access your object then use the url of the cloudfront.
